# MySQL One-To-Many Foreign Key strategy

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table:

**instances**

with the PK called 'id' (int autoincrement)

and two other tables:

**values_text**

**values_int**

these 2 tables have these fields:

**instance_id /
code /
value**

with a PK made by *instance_id* and *code*.

A record of *instance* can have 0, 1 or many related records in *values_text* and *values_int*.

I want to add foreign keys from instances to values_int and values_text so that when I delete a record from *instances* the related records are deleted too from *values_text* and *values_int*.

I was able to create the foreign keys, the problem is that I can't create a record in *instance* table because I get the error:

**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`instances`, CONSTRAINT `instances_fk_ab43df` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `values_text` (`instance_id`))**

How can I set correctly the foreign keys?

Answer (score 2):

you have created the `PK/FK` vice versa, in fact your foreign key is `instance_id` (in both `values_text` and `values_text` tables) not `id` in `instances`.

remove the foreign key constraint on `id` in `instances` instead of it make the foreign key constraint on `instance_id` (in both `values_text` and `values_text` tables) and also leave `id` in `instances` as primary key.

Comment: But if I add the FK to values_text I can't delete the values_text records on CASCADE when I delete the record in instance.  I don't understand if I need to set the FK on the instances table or the values_* ones.